# how is a function navigating through fields of a table

Tags: lua

i already asked this question on stackoverflow and accepted an answer i think i did not really understand the answer and i got some more question, im embarrassed to necro it so im creating a new question

im learning lua and got to metatable part, in this example

```
local tb = {}
local meta = {}

function tb.new(s)
local super = {}
super.s = s

setmetatable(super,meta)

return super
end

function tb.add(s1,s2)

return s1.s..s2.s

end

meta.__add = tb.add

f= tb.new("W")
t= tb.new("E")


print(f+t)
```

when compiler gets to`f = tb.new("W")`
i think this happens
`function tb.new("W")  super.W = W return setmetatable(super,meta) return super end`
so
`print(f+t)`
looks like
`print(super+super)`
how does
`tb.add(super,super)`
find the fields of super table using
`return s1.s..s2.s`
also as the
`tb.new`
function is called twice and
`setmetatable(super,meta)`
happens twice is there any difference between the first and second iteration? if any of the above are incorrect please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when compiler gets to`f = tb.new("W")` i think this happens `function tb.new("W")  super.W = W return setmetatable(super,meta) return super end`

No. It's more like `super['s'] = 'W'`. That's how dot notation works. I hope that clarifies how Lua "finds the fields" later.

> as the `tb.new` function is called twice and `setmetatable(super,meta)` happens twice is there any difference between the first and second iteration?

They're different, because the `super` variable is a new table each time. Any time you see `{}` (a **table constructor**), whether empty or not, it's creating an entirely new table. `meta`, however, is still the same table, because it only gets a table constructor once, outside of any function.

Comment: Thanks 4 the answer. So the answer was so simple ;-; , i was under the impression that `super.s = s` here `s=s` will be replaced by the parameters passed to the function but only the rvalue is replaced so `return s1.s..s2.s` will do `return super.s..super.s` as the table is destroyed and recreated at the 2nd call of the function, table with the same identifier and index can have different value stored as they both are different in some way though in what way . i thought alot 2 reach this point so if im incorrect pls correct me.

Comment: A function's local variables, including its parameters, can refer to different values each time it gets called. That's how `super` refers to totally different tables. The first table isn't really destroyed, because it gets returned and stored in `f`.